# Responsive UI design in android studio

Tags: android, user-interface, responsive-design

I just want to build the page in android studio as shown as [UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jo05.jpg)

Problems :

1> I want to make this page for different screen size but when I run on my physical device, all UI components are shuffled here and there.

2> I have images with different size but I don't how to use them for different screen size.(I can't store these images in drawable folder as I have sub folder)

what I want : Please provide some video tutorials or links so that I can learn to fulfill these requirements.

Advance : I want to know how a software company work like a pro. Means how they create their resources ,manage their projects.(Specially in Android field).

Please Guide me to achieve my dream.
A big THANKS for you.

Answer (score 0):

best way to make your app run in all devices

**-first way is constraint layout**

this is documentation of constraint layout

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

and this is good tutorial to using constraint layout

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuA80lNWNCLICR3qYzhw3iPI

**-second way is sdp-ssp**

sdp: for views sizes
ssp: for textView sizes

this is implementation of sdp and ssp put it in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
```

example for sdp and ssp

android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"

android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"